# Basic Authentication with jQuery.ajax request and jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, basic-authentication

I have some local html/js files with which I'd like to invoke some remote servers via https and eventually use Basic Authentication for the request.

I am encountering two problems. First is that if I don't specify 'jsonp' for the dataType, jQuery.ajax() request returns the error:

> Access to restricted URI denied code:
>   1012

Are my requests considered cross-domain because my main work file is stored locally, but retrieving data from a server elsewhere?

So fine, I update the call so it now looks like:

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: myServerUrl,
     type: "GET", 
     dataType: "jsonp", // considered a cross domain Ajax request if not specified
     username: myUsername,
     password: myPassword,

     success: function(result)
     {
        // success handling
     },
     error: function(req, status, errThrown){
         // error handling
     }
})
```

Because I need to use Basic Authentication, I'm passing in the username/password but if I monitor the request, I don't see it being set and additionally, the server sends an error response since it doesn't have the expected info.

Additionally, because I have `jsonp` set, `beforeSend` won't get invoked.

How do I pass along the credentials using Basic Authentication for this request?

Answer (score 12):

The short version is you can't do this.  Your suspicions are correct, because you're local and these files are remote, you can't access them, you're being blocked by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  The work-around for that is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), but that really doesn't seem to apply to your situation...

JSONP works differently, it's a GET request via a `<script>` tag include to get the file, so you're not sending special headers or anything.

You'll need to proxy the request through the server you're on (the domain of where this script is running) or another proxy option, but going from the client to another domain is blocked, mainly for security reasons.

Comment: This is the correct answer, JSONP cannot contain the USER / PWD headers which Basic Auth requires. So you're damned if you do and damned if you don't :)

Answer (score 7):

Try doing http://user:password@restservice. This mimics a basic-auth request.

Comment: Use of this syntax will be blocked in Chrom from build M59: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to add a server proxy of some sort.  JSONP is just a particular way to use a script tag.  Thus, it doesn't allow setting arbitrary headers.  And of course, you can't do a cross-origin XHR.